# Intellij IDEA plugin development. Action "create kotlin class"

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, intellij-plugin

I want to create a plugin for **Intellij IDEA**. I need to add an action (`AnAction`) that will create a `class` in **Kotlin** (not Java) in a custom `package`. I have two questions:

- How to create files with the desired extension?
- Or how to create a file with **Kotlin** `class`(from some base class) in a custom `package`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way to accomplish this is to use `PsiFileFactory.createFileFromText()` to create an in-memory Kotlin file and then to pass that file as a parameter to `PsiDirectory.add()` to save it to the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Although yole's answer is correct, I would like to see more details about mistery PsiDirectory class.

```
//get directory by VirtualFile
PsiDirectory directory = PsiManager.getInstance(project).findDirectory((getKotlinSourceDir(project))
```

Get kotlin source dir:

```
private VirtualFile getKotlinSourceDir(Project project) {
    return project.getBaseDir().findChild("src").findChild("main").findChild("kotlin");
}
```

And than you can create subdirectories:

```
//someDirectoryName it is simple name 
//(i.e if you post "com.some.package" - it does not create com/some/package folder)
PsiDirectory newDirectory = psiDirectory.createSubdirectory(someDirectoryName);
```

Comment: Please don't use PsiDirectoryFactory.createDirectory(); it's not intended to be used by plugin code. The correct way to get a directory for a virtual file is PsiManager.findDirectory().

Comment: It skips a lot of checks and always returns a new PsiDirectory instance instead of the existing one. To avoid confusion, could you please edit your answer and remove the mention of this method entirely? Thanks!

Comment: Ok. Thanks for explanation!